# Why Jon Skeet has 3K+ badges but SO just shows 300+ ones?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

If you see [Jon Skeet profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=stats) he has 3k+ badges but SO just shows 300+ of them, what are other badges and why there isn't any next,prev for badges?

Comment: It is called `SkeetOverflowException`.

Comment: Maybe we need a new SkeetOverflow badge, awarded when your rep is higher than then number of badges JS has got, and removed if you fall behind to keep the pressure up...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > why there isn't any next,prev for badges?

There is paging for badges in the badges view of specific user, e.g.:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_badges

This also show when he earned each badge. :)

Comment: Several badges every day! If he didn't log for a few days, his whole screen must be taken up with new badge notifications.

Comment: @mikel if he "didn't log for a few days" it means the end of Stack Overflow as we know it... :-P

Comment: If you receive several badges at once there is only one notification bar - my one right now says "You've earned "Popular Question" and 3 other badges. See your profile."

Comment: "You've earned 'Nice Question' and 254 other badges. See your profile. Now! Do it finally!"  :)

Answer (score 17):

There are some badges he has received several times.

Comment: "several" as in 1835 Nice Answer badges at the time of this writing.

Comment: He received the `Nice Answer`-Badge already 1,800 times.

Comment: nice, I don't know why i didn't see them :)